# Kohana controllers and response body

Tags: php, frameworks, backend, kohana

So i have a site with following url: http://www.resistance.nhely.hu/

Im using Kohana as backend, and Angular5 as frontend, BUT my Kohana backend is not working perfectly... and i dont know why.

So here is two different URL

First one: http://www.resistance.nhely.hu/progresses/list_all (its return with json encode, and its working fine)

Second one: http://www.resistance.nhely.hu/recruits/list_all (im using same return json encode method, but in this URL showing nothing as response)

Both query have value (if i var_dump them its filled with data)

Any tip what is the problem?

Uploaded two image:

[Recruits Controller action_list_all()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d07G0.png)

[Progresses Controller action_list_all()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL1Gs.png)

Edit: In my localhost both url have response

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

There are 2 possible reasons:

1. Empty response in the browser cache: In debugger, `Network` tab set "Disable cache"
2. You have an error in the code: Look in `php_error.log` or Kohana logs

BTW: Why you don't use `->execute()->`[as_array](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide-api/Database_Result#as_array)`()`

BTW2: It's good idea move this to [Model](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide-api/ORM). (Add method, not use ORM query builder. Fething to objects are very slow)